# How to broadcast a UDP packet on WP7 Mango?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to send a UDP packet from a phone to the limited broadcast address (IPAddress.Broadcast = 255.255.255.255).

This is what I have so far, and it works in a Windows app:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);   
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);   

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test data");   

SocketAsyncEventArgs a = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();   

a.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 11000);   
a.SetBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);   

a.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.SocketError);
});

socket.SendToAsync(a);
```

The SetSocketOption call is required in order to prevent an "access denied" exception. Unfortunately that method doesn't seem to be available on WP7.  The UDP sample code given on the App Hub community site is using multicast to achieve similar results, but the device I'm trying to contact isn't able to deal with multicast.

Is there any way to do this sort of broadcast on Mango?

Comment: I added a Completed event to the code to allow examining the SocketError, which shows AccessDenied. If you change this to do normal (non-async) socket calls, leaving out the SetSocketOption call, you'll get the AccessDenied exception. But you only get the Async calls in Mango.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`socket.ConnectAsync(a);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

**From Documentation:**

Optionally, a buffer may be provided which will atomically be sent on the socket after the ConnectAsync method succeeds. (UDP is a connectionless protocol, should send always when network works)

Comment: ConnectAsync actually sends the data if you have a buffer set!?

Comment: I got this to work finally. Interestingly, I can only get it to work on WP7. When running it in Windows I get a "bad parameter" error.

Comment: Also, according to the documentation, ConnectAsync is supposed to throw an exception if an attempt is made to connect to a broadcast address and the socket option hasn't been set. So this shouldn't really be working, and I'm not sure I want to rely on this behavior.

Comment: @crappy Only in Net 4 Documentation. In Silverlight Documentation not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Skomski. I often miss which version of the documentation I'm looking at. :/

Comment: I get a SocketError.Success even when the remote host is powered down!.. interesting...