# UDP broadcasting in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working an application in windows phone 7 that must detect the devices connected to particular port no or  network. I have desktop application that is implemented in c++ that uses UDP broadcast. I read some articles and know windows phone 7 doesn't support UDP broadcasting. I have tried UDP multicasting in WP7 but due to desktop application have implemented in UDP broadcast, I am not able to do that.
Help me Guys...........

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Mango, this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983815/how-to-broadcast-a-udp-packet-on-wp7-mango

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socket.ConnectAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) with [e.Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.buffer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) containing the message you want to broadcast. In this case, the message will be sent automatically when connection is established. More information about this trick you can read [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/88975.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to receive the response back?

Answer (score 0):

You could send a broadcast packet through just SendToAsync method by using limited broadcast IP, not local broadcast IP(such as 255.255.255.255) This means, if your NIC device is in 192.168.0.x IP range, you should shoot a packet to **192.168.0.255**. (this IP might be vary on your netmask setting)

However, it works.

Additionally, response back is also allowed but FOR 5 SECONDS ONLY. Your host received a UDP packet from Windows Phone 7.1 device, the host should response back to the port that UDP packet came from, IN 5 SECONDS. Unless, Windows Phone will close the port then, and it has to be gone.

It's very tricky, weird, and ununderstandable(like this word) way.
but it works as far I know.