# Device Discovery in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-7

i am not able to detect devices present in the network.
There are two application I am using. One is written in C++ and another is windows phone 7 app. From Wp7 i am sending UDP broadcast that I referred from [How to broadcast a UDP packet on WP7 Mango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983815/how-to-broadcast-a-udp-packet-on-wp7-mango.Now) I am able to broadcast message from wp7 and receiving in C++ app.But I am not able to receive UDP packet from C++ code.
Here is my code.
C# code

```
private void PageTitle_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255");
            var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 4998);
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello|4998");
            var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.RemoteEndPoint = endpoint;
            args.SetBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);
            args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(args_Completed);
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Dgram,
                ProtocolType.Udp);
            bool result = socket.ConnectAsync(args);

        }

        void args_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch (e.LastOperation)
            {
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Connect:
                    bool res = e.ConnectSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(e);
                    break;

                case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                    break;

                case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

C++ code

```
ServerAddress.sin_family= AF_INET; 
ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr= INADDR_ANY;
ServerAddress.sin_port  = htons (PORT_DESKTOP); 
ServerSocket = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

sendto (ServerSocket, Buffer, sizeof (Buffer), 0, (LPSOCKADDR) &ClientAddress, Length);
```

I have also used creating another socket using IPADDRESS.Any to receive the message.But I am not able to receive response from c++ code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you miss enabling **SO_BROADCAST**?

[SOL_SOCKET Socket Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **SO_BROADCAST**  yes yes DWORD (boolean) Configure a socket for sending
>   broadcast data. This option is only Valid for protocols that support
>   broadcasting (IPX and UDP, for example).