# How to receive UDP data in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, udp, windows-phone-7.1

I want to prepare app on Windows Phone 7.1 to sending/receiving UDP datagrams between camera and phone (Wanscam camera). I've read many discussions about this and now I don't know it's possible on OS 7.1.

At the beginning I have to find camera IP. I wrote some code based on [Device Discovery in Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574623/device-discovery-in-windows-phone-7):

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IP_BROADCAST);
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portToScan);
byte[] data = packet.GetRawPacketBytes();
var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
args.RemoteEndPoint = endpoint;
args.SetBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);
args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    recevingEnabled = true;
    Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
    while (recevingEnabled)
    {
        Receive(portToScan);
    }
});
bool result = socket.SendToAsync(args);
```

Method to receiving:

```
public void Receive(int portNumber)
{
    SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);
    socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        clientDone.Set();
    });

    clientDone.Reset();
    socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
    clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
}
```

1) When I invoke this method I receive data from my camera but I can't find the sender IP address in socketEventArg. 
2) I don't know it's possible to receive more datagrams when in local network were connected more cameras.

Next point is more strange for me. I'd like to listen on port and receiving datagrams which camera will send to phone (only datagrams from camera IP). I don't know it's possible according to the source: [Sockets for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

My approach looks like while(true) TryReceiving; But it wasn't working. I decided to check udp communication between simple python script on my laptop and my simple WP7 app. I was suprising when I looked at the result.

I plugged my phone (192.168.1.102) to laptop (192.168.1.104) and begun debugging. Next I sent some datagram to laptop. My laptop received datagram in python script and forwarded message. Unfortunatelly my phone app wasn't able to receive any datagram. I try to solve this problem but I can't understand where is the problem. I sniff my network via Wireshark and I see my laptop forward message to phone. I tried to change **ReceiveAsync** to **ReceiveFromAsync** and **SendToAsync** to **SendAsync** in every combination.

Code:

```
private void ReceiveTask()
{

    byte[] data = currentStunServer.HelloToAddressPacket().GetRawPacketBytes();
    SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.104"), 32110);
    socketEventArg.SetBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);
    socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg2 = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg2.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.104"), 32110);
            socketEventArg2.SetBuffer(new Byte[2048], 0, 2048);

            socketEventArg2.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s2, SocketAsyncEventArgs e2)
            {
                if (e2.BytesTransferred > 0)
                {
                    string response;
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e2.Buffer, e.Offset, e2.BytesTransferred);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');
                }
                clientDone.Set();
            });

            clientDone.Reset();
            UdpSocket2.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg2);
            clientDone.WaitOne(1000);
        }
    });

    bool result = UdpSocket2.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);

    while (true)
    {
        Receive();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Is there any approach to solve the problem? Maybe Windows Phone 8 provides some solutions? 
Sorry for my English.